# How to get a notification when a webpage is updated?

Tags: rss, notifications, feeds

I have to monitor a page for changes, but the page has no feeds. I was using Yahoo Pipes to generate a RSS for pages like that. But it is too cumbersome just to check if the main HTML checksum has changed.
Is there a tool that does that for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ChangeDetection](http://www.changedetection.com/) and [ChangeDetect](http://www.changedetect.com/) provide these services for you.

They are both free and both provide email notifications.

Comment: The first one also provide feeds.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try to https://www.wachete.com
It supports monitor of whole page, or just it's part, files, content of files, HTML headers, provides RSS feed of changes, email notifications and even plugged to zapier.